# I'm passing 2 tables of data into a single view but I am getting an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm getting an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[jetjourneys.ViewModel.ItineraryPage]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'jetjourneys.ViewModel.ItineraryPage

Code:

```
public class ItineraryPage
{
    public PackageGallery Package { get; set; }
    public tblItinerary Itinerarydetail { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult ItineraryPackage(int id)
{
        using (travelAndTourismEntities objentity = new travelAndTourismEntities())
        {
            var query = (from x in objentity.tblItineraries
                         from y in objentity.PackageGalleries
                         where x.Imageid == id && y.Imageid == id
                         select new ItineraryPage { Package = y, Itinerarydetail = x });
            return View(query);
        }
}
```

This is my controller please help me where I'm making a mistake

Comment: That LINQ query returns a `DbQuery<ItineraryPage>` - not an actual, single `ItineraryPage` - you need to do a `.FirstOrDefault` or something like that on the query result to pass into the view

Answer (score 0):

You are still returning the `IQueryable` object instead of the actual result, this should work

[FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549141(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
public ActionResult ItineraryPackage(int id)
{
        using (travelAndTourismEntities objentity = new travelAndTourismEntities())
        {
            var query = (from x in objentity.tblItineraries
                         from y in objentity.PackageGalleries
                         where x.Imageid == id && y.Imageid == id
                         select new ItineraryPage { Package = y, Itinerarydetail = x });

            return View(query.FirstOrDefault()); //Update here
        }
}
```